# Issue with Scope_identity() when used with TransactionScope()

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, .net, sql-server

I am using TransactionScope() such that ..

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(); 
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure; 
cmd.CommandText = "proc_insertlot"; cmd.Connection = sqlconn; 
da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);

    for (int i = 0; i < 3 i++)
    {         
          da.Fill(ds);//this insert a row in a table which has identity column
          LotId = ds.Tables[1].Rows[0][0].ToString();//always return same identityvalue
    }
```

//---TransactionScope commit

It seems that unless i commit the transaction, scope_identity wont increment. In this example scope_identity will return the same value all the 3 times. How do you I solve this?

**SQL:**

```
ALTER  procedure proc_insertlot      
@AuctionId int=0,      
@Title varchar(300)='',      
@Description varchar(4000)='',      
@lottype varchar(20)='',      
@ImproveBidBy varchar(20)='',      
@BidDecrement varchar(20)='',      
@FrontBuffer varchar(20)='',      
@BackBuffer varchar(20)='',      
@AttachmentId varchar(30)='',      
@MkrId varchar(11)=''  ,    
@file_uploadlot varchar(30) =''    
as      
      set nocount on 
insert into tbl_lots(AuctionId,Title,Description,lottype,ImproveBidBy,BidDecrement,FrontBuffer,BackBuffer,AttachmentId,MkrId,MkrDt)      
 values (@AuctionId,@Title,@Description,@lottype,@ImproveBidBy,@BidDecrement,@FrontBuffer,@BackBuffer,@AttachmentId,@MkrId,GETDATE())   

select @@Identity as lotid
```

Comment: usually, da is data adapter and ds is data set, so da.Fill(ds) selects records from the database, not inserting records to it....

Comment: @ZoharPeled
 SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    cmd.CommandText = "proc_insertlot";
                    cmd.Connection = sqlconn;
                    da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);

Comment: @Arbaaz - if you want to add more code, please [edit] your question, so that you can use the formatting tool (`{}`) Code in comments is practically unreadable.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever  .. done

Comment: @AmitRanjan - no problem. I could of course have done that myself, but I try to *encourage* the OPs to do this kind of work so that they get the hang of editing, making improvements to their question based on comments, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it will work. Changing Rows[0][0] -> Rows[i][0]

```
for (int i = 0; i < 3 i++)
{         
      da.Fill(ds);//this insert a row in a table which has identity column
      LotId = ds.Tables[1].Rows[i][0].ToString();//will now return required identityvalue
}
```

See if it works or not.

**Update**

Got your problem. Issue is that 
`LotId = ds.Tables[1].Rows[0][0].ToString();` will  always return the last most value of `scope_identity` as soon as scope is committed. Instead you can try `@@Identity`. Also check if you have AutoIncrement enabled with PK. Generally we use AutoIncrement Columns as PK.

e.g. courtsey : Guffa.

```
    create procedure proc_insertlot
    as
    set nocount on
declare @id as int
    insert into SomeTable (
      SomeField
    ) values (
      42
    )

    SET @Id=@@Identity
    SELECT @ID
```

Comment: How is this going to fix it? there is only one select statement in the procedure  select SCOPE_IDENTITY() as lotid

The value will always be return in the first row

Comment: @Arbaaz - Actually I am little confused with your code. If youknow its in Rows[0][0], then whats the need of loop. Are you trying to execute Scope Identity thrice and getting it thrice too, is it so.

Comment: There is a need for loop in my scenario. This is just a simple example which somewhat demonstrates my problem. There is an insert sql procedure `proc_insertlot` that will execute from withing the loop each time. This procedure has ` select SCOPE_IDENTITY() as lotid` . Now assuming the table is blank at the beginning , basically this code is supposed to return identity value 1 the first time insert proc is executed,  2 on second iteration and so on.

Comment: It still returns same value

Comment: My apologies, your first solution worked. I did not notice that each time i execute procedure the the result returned is in a new row.

Answer (score 0):

For this to work, you need:

- A key in the table
- The key needs to have the setting Identity = true
- The procedure needs `set nocount on` to suppress the result of the insert

Example:

```
create procedure proc_insertlot
as

set nocount on

insert into SomeTable (
  SomeField
) values (
  42
)

select scope_identity()
```

Comment: It still returns same value everytime

Answer (score 0):

ExecuteScalar is used for return ID of last inserted record and you can return id by using this

```
select Scope_Identity
```

May this helps you solve your problem.